# ¿es posible realizar un return de la funcion principal main en GO?

Tags: go

La idea principal es crear un .exe en GO que realiza múltiples peticiones hhtp. Este seria llamado desde un programa en python pasándole los parámetros necesarios (url, data, etc).
La duda que tengo es ¿como puedo generar un return del exe para capturar los datos en una variable Python?. Por lo que verifique la funcion main() en GO no me permite return.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar `os.Exit` como se indica en este [ejemplo](https://gobyexample.com/exit).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    defer fmt.Println("!")

    os.Exit(3)
}
```

La función main no retorna un int como C o C++, pero puedes tener el mismo comportamiento con esta función.